# For a d3js graph with x equal to time since boot (not since epoch), I want better x-axis tick labels

Tags: javascript, date, d3.js, graph, epoch

In a d3js graph with time on the x-axis, I want to display better tick labels when an ntp reference is not available (and user did not set the date otherwise).  In a device with no ntp server, the timestamps may just be recorded as number of seconds since boot up.  When that is the situation, I don't want to report the graph times as some crazy wall clock time, hh:mm, in 1970 or 1971, which is what I get by default.

One option would be to adjust the timestamps by adding timediff into each timestamp, where:

```
timediff = client.timenow - server.timenow
```

symbolic of calling "time(0)" on the client and the server and getting the diff.  That works if the client/browser system has a (good) ntp server (and assuming we know the server time and timestamps are clearly zero-based.  But, if the client also does not have a proper time reference, what should I display?

An option would be to show (days, hours, minutes, seconds) since the device started counting time, perhaps in a format like:

```
Days HH:MM:SS
  93 12:01:05
```

with a time axis label like "Elapsed time since boot".  Time axis labels could use just HH:MM:SS until a boundary 24 hour point is hit and then throw in something like "Day 94" at a more major tick mark.

Any suggestions on how to handle this case?  I skimmed D3's time and time interval options but didn't see a solution.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you've talked around your actual problem. It seems you have values that represent time since some epoch, but you don't know what the epoch is. Why can't you just reduce the values to an arbitrary datum (say the lowest value) and express them as hours, minutes etc. since then? That should not be difficult. You haven't provided any criteria for determining the best solution, so really answers are left to guessing.

Comment: Thanks RobG.  Re: Criteria for best solution, I'm asking for input/opinions, but proposing something like this (for two tick marks): "93 days\n12:01:00 ... 93 days\n12:02:00 etc" but it's a bit messy.  I don't know the time of boot other than as time=0.  If I can't tie boot to a timestamp with more "legitimacy", then all I can say is boot happened about "93 days, 12 hours, and 1 minute ago". Not quite sure I understood your comment fully - Please clarify if not.

Comment: I'm also wondering what MRTG (or others) do in the same situation.

Comment: I've been asked to stick with time known on the server (a router) instead of doing the trick of adding the time difference (where timediff = client.timenow - server.timenow) to each "seconds since boot" value.  This makes it even more important to find a solution.  The likely format will be "123:23:59:59" for 123 days, and one second less than midnight.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think you're off topic here. This place is about solutions to specific programming issues, not the logic. Once you work out what you want to do we can help with the coding, but this seems to be a fairly domain–specific issue that, while interesting, is OT. I just don't now enough about SNMP or MRTG to offer any help. :-(